# Why isn't matches with regex storing to the dictionary properly?

Tags: python, regex, dictionary, python-re

For my assignment I have to use regex and code chunking to find all URL's inside a raw data file.  For some reason when I find the matches it's not matching URL's but it's finding numbers?  The dictionary is getting filled with numbers instead of matches.  The problem I believe is somewhere in the "for URL in fileContents".  I have been trying to trouble shoot this for hours, it is looping and looks for matches using urlPattern but for some reason it's finding number and not actual URL's?  The Regex isn't the issue either because I used this for a simplified test and it finds the URL's.  Another issue I noticed is that if I input 50 for chunkSize it only ever checks the first 50 bytes, I'm not sure what's the best approach for it to start with that chunk but continue to check the whole file?

Here is the code I have

```
import re
import os
import sys
from prettytable import PrettyTable

largeFile = input("Enter the name of a large File: ")
chunkSize = int(input("What size chunks?  "))

urlPattern = re.compile(b'\w+:\/\/[\w@][\w.:@]+\/?[\w\.?=%&=\-@/$,]*')
matches = {}

try:
    if os.path.isfile(largeFile):
        with open(largeFile, 'rb') as targetFile:
            fileContents = targetFile.read(chunkSize)


            


            print("\nURLs")

            for URL in fileContents:
                try:
                    urlMatches   = urlPattern.findall(fileContents)
                    cnt = matches[URL]
                    cnt += 1
                    matches[URL] = cnt
                    print(urlMatches)
                    print(URL)
                except:
                    matches[URL] = 1


            tbl = PrettyTable(["Words", "Occurrences"])
            for word, cnt in matches.items():
                tbl.add_row([word, cnt])
                tbl.align = 'l'
                for link, count in matches:
                    tbl.add_row([link, count])
                print(tbl.get_string(sortby="Occurrences", reversesort=True))
                break
    else:
        print(largeFile, " is not a valid file")
        sys.exit("Script Aborted")

except Exception as err:
    print(err)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `for URL in fileConents` line is simply iterating over a bunch of numbers.

To demonstrate lets assume that the first chunk of the file we read contains `b"https://www.example.website.com/page/1"`:

```
>>> fileContents = b"https://www.example.website.com/page/1"
>>> for URL in fileContents:
...    print(URL)
...
104
116
116
112
115
58
47
47
119
```

As you can see when you iterate over a byte string, individual bytes are converted into integers.

I think this is probably closer at least to what you are trying to achieve.

```
import re
import os
import sys
from prettytable import PrettyTable

largeFile = input("Enter the name of a large File: ")
chunkSize = int(input("What size chunks?  "))

print(largeFile, chunkSize)

urlPattern = re.compile(b'\w+:\/\/[\w@][\w.:@]+\/?[\w\.?=%&=\-@/$,]*')
matches = {}

try:
    if os.path.isfile(largeFile):
        with open(largeFile, 'rb') as targetFile:
            fileContents = targetFile.read(chunkSize)

            # while there is data left in the file
            while len(fileContents) > 0:
                # find all the urls inside this filecontents chunk
                urlMatches = urlPattern.findall(fileContents) 

                # for each of the found urls
                for match in urlMatches:

                    # create a dictionary key if one doesn't exist
                    matches.setdefault(match, 0)

                    # increase the count value 
                    matches[match] += 1
                 
                # read in the next chunk of data from the file
                fileContents = targetFile.read(chunkSize)

            tbl = PrettyTable(["Words", "Occurrences"])
            for word, cnt in matches.items():
                tbl.add_row([word, cnt])
            tbl.align = 'l'
            print(tbl.get_string(sortby="Occurrences", reversesort=True))
    else:
        print(largeFile, " is not a valid file")
        sys.exit("Script Aborted")

except Exception as err:
    print(err)
```

This is my output:

```
+--------------------------+-------------+
| Words                    | Occurrences |
+--------------------------+-------------+
| b'https://www.dod.mil'   | 1           |
| b'https://treasury.gov'  | 1           |
| b'https://microsoft.com' | 1           |
| b'http://www.google.com' | 1           |
| b'http://www.amazon.com' | 1           |
+--------------------------+-------------+
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.  For some reason I get "python too many values to unpack (expected 2)" when I run this.  I think it's because you have fileContents for the second run.  So you're reading the chunkSize twice?  I think I need to iterate over chunk sizes outside the for loop?

Comment: @Java_Assembly55  That isn't why... can you paste the full traceback

Comment: @Java_Assembly55  I think i fixed it... the problem was with your last for loop so I just removed it.  Try it now

Comment: It says "too many values to unpack (expected 2)"

Comment: I need to find all URL's inside this test.bin file.  If I open the file in an IDE it is clear text but I guess my professor said to open it was "rb".  Once I find all the URL's I print it out in a pretty table.

Comment: @Java_Assembly55  Try running it now.  If it still doesn't work then maybe you can copy and paste your file into a pastebin so I can test it

Comment: I'm still getting that error.  Here is just a snippet of it, it was too large to really upload.  It's just really a bunch of random stuff but has links at the end.  The idea it to find the links and prettytable print them https://pastebin.com/SNmFxTCV

Comment: @Java_Assembly55  It worked perfectly fine for me.    try hardcoding the name of the file and the chunksize instead of asking for input from the user and see if it changes anythiong maybe

Comment: @Java_Assembly55  It worked perfectly fine for me.    try hardcoding the name of the file and the chunksize instead of asking for input from the user and see if it changes anythiong maybe.  Or try directly copying and pasting the code in my example.  If it worked for me there is no reason it shouldn't work for you too

Comment: You are the man! Been trying to figure this out for like 2 days.  it's working now, no idea what it didn't work before.  Will mark your answer up.  I'll analyze your code more and make sure I understand it.  Could you maybe trying to explain exactly what I was doing wrong though?  It's still a little confusing for me.

Comment: @Java_Assembly55  Its hard for me to explain what you were doing wrong because I am not really sure what you were trying to do in your original code.  The first part of my answer shows why the line `for URL in fileContents:`  all it is doing is iterating over a bunch of numbers so it clearly isn't doing what you want it to.  Everything after that point isn't really clear what you were trying to do.  If you look at the notes I made in my code it should provide a decent explanation.

Comment: Thank you.  I am reviewing it now.  The one thing I was a little confused on, is the part it reads in the next chunk of data?  How exactly does it check the next chunk of data?  If it's on a loop wouldn't it keep reading the same data chunk?

Comment: no... every time you call `myfile.read(chunksize)` it returns the next chunksize portion of the file.  When you call `open('myfile.txt')` you shouldn't think of the return value as a file you should think of it as a stream.  so when you call read it will return next portion of the stream. @Java_Assembly55

Comment: So in other words it reads in the first chunk before the loop starts, then the loop itself checks the length of the chunk and if it's 0 then it doesn't continue.  inside of the loop it processes the data that is inside of the chunk, and then at the very end it replaces reads in the next chunk and the loop starts again from the beginning.  When the file is finaly empty it returns an embty bytestring which makes it stop looping.  @Java_Assembly55